# if res.end not called, http server can't handle new requests?

Tags: node.js

I have this code :

```
var http = require('http');
var count = 0;
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    //....
    if (req.url == '/') {
        count++;
        console.log('request' + count + ' enter:' + new Date())
        setTimeout(function() {
            res.end('response data');
            console.log('request' + count + ' leave:' + new Date())
        }, 3000)
        console.log('end')
    }
}).listen(3000)
```

then I open browser, open three tabs visiting my server quickly.

what I expect was:

```
request1 enter: ...
end
request2 enter: ...
end
request3 enter: ...
end
request1 leave: ...
request2 leave: ...
request3 leave: ...
```

but actually it was:

[image]

every request is block by the previous one.

Is this because I'm testing on local side

there's some connection issue?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectation are (almost) correct.

So why you dont receive correct output? It is actually behaviour of browser. At least chrome - when I open 3 tabs at once and request localhost:3000 from all of them, it was not sending 3 requests - it sends only one and wait for response before using other one.

I have used 1 curl command and 1 chrome request "at once" (it means I clicked these as fast as I could) and this is what happends:

[image]

The only part where you were not correct in your expectation was the value of "leave" responses as at that time, the "count" is equal the same for all of them.

---

To receive exactly desired output, you can remember the actual count in your function scope:

```
var http = require('http');
var count = 0;
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    //....
    if (req.url == '/') {
        count++;
        var requestCount = count;
        console.log('request' + requestCount + ' enter:' + new Date())
        setTimeout(function() {
            res.end('response data');
            console.log('request' + requestCount + ' leave:' + new Date())
        }, 3000)
        console.log('end')
    }
}).listen(3000)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and testing!